# Is it possible to simulate a touch or click at a certain x/y coordinate?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Is it possible to simulate a touch or click at a certain x/y coordinate?

I'm not looking to fireEvent on a view or an object, rather I know a set of coordinates and I want to simulate a touch or click at that location and whatever would normally happen if someone touched that spot should happen.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to "simulate" this by just binding a named function to your click event and then call that function by name.

```
var sim = function(event){
  ...
};

$.view.addEventListener('click', sim);

//simulate
sim({x: 100, y: 100});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking is that you want to run some code only when user taps in a particular area or on particular co-ordinates. For this, you can use **onClick** event and then **x** & **y** attributes of arguments.

Something like this:

```
$.view.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   Ti.API.info('Clicked at :: X = ' + event.x + ' & Y = ' + event.y);
});
```

Comment: I actually want to accomplish the inverse